# Python, Make variable equal to the second column of an array

Tags: python, list, indexing, list-comprehension, min

I realise that there's a fair chance this has been asked somewhere else, but to be honest I'm not sure exactly what terminology I should be using to search for it.
But basically I've got a list with a varying number of elements. Each element contains 3 values: A string, another list, and an integer eg:

> First element = ('A', [], 0)

so

> ListofElements[0] = [('A', [], 0)]

And what I am trying to do is make a new list that consists of all of the integers(3rd thing in the elements) that are given in ListofElements.

I can do this already by stepping through each element of ListofElements and then appending the integer onto the new list shown here:

```
NewList=[]
for element in ListofElements:
    NewList.append(element[2])
```

But using a for loop seems like the most basic way of doing it, is there a way that uses less code? Maybe a list comprehension or something such as that. It seems like something that should be able to be done on a single line.

---

That is just a step in my ultimate goal, which is to find out the index of the element in ListofElements that has the minimum integer value. So my process so far is to make a new list, and then find the integer index of that new list using:

```
index=NewList.index(min(NewList))
```

Is there a way that I can just avoid making the new list entirely and generate the index straight away from the original ListofElements? I got stuck with what I would need to fill in to here, or how I would iterate through :

```
min(ListofElements[?][2])
```

Comment: You mean `NewList = [element[2] for element in ListofElements]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a list coprehension:

```
[x[2] for x in ListOfElements]
```

This is generally considered a "Pythonic" approach.

You can also find the minimum in a rather stylish manner using:

```
minimum = min(ListOfElements, key=lambda x: x[2])
index = ListOfElements.index(minimum)
```

**Some general notes:**

1. In python using underscores is the standard rather than CamelCase.
2. In python you almost never have to use an explicit for loop. Instead prefer
   coprehensions or a functional pattern (`map`, `apply` etc.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer and pointers, I'm still very new to python so am still getting the hang of comprehensions. After that it I'll have to have a look at lambda functions too!

Answer (score 0):

You can `map` your list with [`itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter):

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> l = [(1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 3)]
>>> map(itemgetter(2), l)
[3, 3, 3, 3, 3]
```

Then you can go with your approach to find the position of minimum value.